# Using a Sass variable called like a mixin

Tags: css, variables, sass, mixins

In Sass, I'm not sure what to search for. I want something like:

```
$dark = function($perc) {
    $decimal = $perc/100%;
    return rgba(0,0,0,$decimal);
}
.bar { box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px $dark(40%); }
```

So... call a variable like a `@mixin`? I don't know. I'm sure this is doable, I just don't know how or how to research it.

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation at all?

Comment: Sure did. It's long. I've only been digging into Sass for the past 4 days. I hate stupid questions on SO as much as anybody, but it didn't even occur to me to search for "Sass functions"... I just had `@mixins` on my mind. Didn't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SASS those are simply called functions. In your case this would be

```
@function dark($percent) {
   @return rgba(0,0,0, $percent / 100);
}
```

You can then use it like so

```
.bar { box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px dark(40); }
```

Comment: :) had to wait the requisite 8 minutes before I could accept it.